# Is the class loaded when its reference is declared?

Tags: java, class, reference, initialization, loading

Does creating a reference to an object of a class cause the class to be loaded?

Static variables are initialized when the class is loaded, so considering the following code the answer is no, am I right?

```
    class A{
        static int f(){
            System.out.println("initializing!");
            return 0;
        }
        static final int i = f();
    }
    public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            A a;
        }
    }
```

The code doesn't give any output.

Comment: Why don't you test yourself? Add a static initializer to `A` that prints something to `System.out`: `static { System.out.println("initializing A"); }`

Comment: You haven't yet instantiated the "A", If you instantiate it, the static block will be called.
A a = new A();

Comment: Yes, becouse I just wanted to ask if creating the reference causes class loading.

Comment: It might help understanding that unused local variables are a compile-time artifact. When you compile that class without debug information, there will be no reference to `A` inside the class file of `Main`

Comment: Thanks @Holger it realy helped me to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Static initializers are called when a class method is called or an instance is instantiated.

From your example you can do one of the following:

#### 1. Create New Instance

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
}
```

#### 2. Call Static Class Method

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int f = A.f();
}
```

Comment: Maybe worth showing in your example that `A.f();` would also cause the class to be loaded.

Comment: It took me a minute to understand that “Yes” is the answer to “the answer is no, am I right?”. Considering the question’s title, having “Yes.” as the answer’s first sentence is a bit unfortunate. I suggest rewording it, maybe avoiding “yes” and “no” entirely, only stating the fact that merely declaring a variable does not trigger class initialization.

Comment: @Holger The "Yes" is in response to the title question. Do you genuinely feel that it's confusing? Should I just remove the "Yes" completely?

Comment: I think, the problem is that the title contains yes/no question and the main question also contains yes/no question and answer for them is different. It's a bit confusing at first view.

Answer (score 6):

It’s a common mistake to treat loading and initialization of a class as being the same thing.

The [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/index.html) differentiates between

- [Loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)

  > *Loading* refers to the process of finding the binary form of a class or interface type with a particular name, perhaps by computing it on the fly, but more typically by retrieving a binary representation previously computed from source code by a Java compiler, and constructing, from that binary form, a `Class` object to represent the class or interface.
- [Linking](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.3)

  > *Linking* is the process of taking a binary form of a class or interface type and combining it into the run-time state of the Java Virtual Machine, so that it can be executed. A class or interface type is always loaded before it is linked.
  >
  > Three different activities are involved in linking: verification, preparation, and resolution of symbolic references.
- [Initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)

  > *Initialization* of a class consists of executing its `static` initializers and the initializers for static fields (class variables) declared in the class.
  > *Initialization* of an interface consists of executing the initializers for fields (constants) declared in the interface.

For most cases, the exact time of loading and linking doesn’t matter, so it’s no problem that the specification provides some freedom to JVM implementations regarding the exact time. Only in the erroneous case, e.g. when a class is absent or there are incompatibilities (linkage or verify errors), JVM specific differences can show up, regarding the exact time when the associated `Error` is thrown.

So what your question is aiming at, is not *loading*, but *initialization* as you are looking at the side effect produced by the execution of the `static` class intializer.

The time of initialization is [precisely defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> #### §12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - `T` is a class and an instance of `T` is created.
> - A `static` method declared by `T` is invoked.
> - A `static` field declared by `T` is assigned.
> - A `static` field declared by `T` is used and the field is not a constant variable ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)).
> - `T` is a top level class ([§7.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6)) and an `assert` statement ([§14.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10)) lexically nested within `T` ([§8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3)) is executed.
>
> When a class is initialized, its superclasses are initialized (if they have not been previously initialized), as well as any superinterfaces ([§8.1.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)) that declare any default methods ([§9.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4.3)) (if they have not been previously initialized). Initialization of an interface does not, of itself, cause initialization of any of its superinterfaces.

So from the specification, you can draw the conclusion that the mere presence of a local variable will never trigger an initialization. When assigning a non-`null` value to a variable of a reference type, there must have been a preceding instantiation of that type that already triggered its initialization. An unused local variable, however, has no impact.

When it comes to *loading* rather than initialization, there can be subtle differences, as shown is [this scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38673384/2711488).

Comment: Well explained, now I not only know, but also understand. Your answer was really helpfull. Thanx alot!