# When does class loading takes place in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, oop, jvm

In java, how would you prove that class loading takes place only once and that loading may be caused by either the creation of the first instance of that class or by the access of a static member. Can you explain how to do this on Eclipse if the way we prove changes with IDE ?

Comment: Use the `-verbose:class` command line switch for Java to print exactly when a class is loaded. That should provide all the tools you need to dig into specific class loading behaviour.

Comment: You prove it by pointing to the part of the spec that says that this is what happens.

Comment: You could put a break-point into the classloader. Or turn on the JVM flag that prints classloading information. Or put a `println` into a static initializer of the class (if you can trust that those get called exactly when the class is loaded).

Comment: You are confusing loading and initialization. Loading happens at an implementation specific time. Initialization happens on one of the triggers [listed in the specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1). See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39268133/2711488).

Answer (score -1):

class loading doesn't depends upon whether you make an instance of class or not. Whenever you run java program first compiler will convert it into .classFile.
Then this .class file is send to ClassLoader. Inside class loader **Loader** loads this .class file from the secondary storage or hard disk . And after loading .class file **Loader** send this file to **Linker** then Linker verify and prepare the code and send for **Intialization**. 
Then send this file into memory of java.
Then Execution engine.
So the loading takes place only once whenever we run java program.